# SQL Server Character_set and Collation

Tags: sql-server, character-encoding

I'm running an app with the  database storage on SQL SERVER 2012.

The columns of my table are varchar(s), I'm using cp1253  for character set and 
the collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI.

The problem now is that I need to store data from German language(with 
the special chars like umlaut .

I tried to change the columns to nvarchar , so the character set now
is Unicode but the columns still cannot recognize the special chars (ö, ä, ü ).

In case we have constrains such as non unique index I assume
that I have to re-create the index.

Any ideas are Welcome.